# MySql Replication Force Delays

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I'm maintaing one test Env in my company.

And I'm uptating the test Databases as slaves of the Production ones.

What I need to know is if there is anyaways of updating this specific slave just 1 or 2 times a day, not almost in realtime it is at the moment?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a configurable option to do this.

However slaves will happily pick up from wherever they left off if they are disconnected from the master. With this in mind, you could script `STOP SLAVE`/`START SLAVE` commands at the intervals you require.

You will probably want to ensure that the slaves are finished replicating to-date using the [`Seconds_Behind_Master`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-slave-status.html) value or [`mk-table-checksum`](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) before stopping them again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin method to do so. If you only want to resync once or twice a day, I suggest you follow the route pointed out by Dan Carley.

If you want the database to *lag behind* a specified amount of time, say - a few hours, you could use [mk-slave-delay](http://code.google.com/p/maatkit/source/browse/trunk/mk-slave-delay/mk-slave-delay) from [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/). This will automaically balance the `START SLAVE`/`STOP SLAVE` cycle to maintain the defined delay.

Comment: Did you read the question? MySQL's binary execution is very slow and could take hours depending on volume. I would recommend a file level copy if the goal is to catch up once per day and not continuously.

Comment: I read the question, did you read the answer? I suggested an alternative. Also, it is a failure to suggest a file level copy being superior to binary replication without knowledge of replication volume nor dataset size.